# Twitter Bootstrap not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi~ I am trying to implement Twitter Bootstrap but it is not working! I downloaded latest version of Twitter Bootstrap ( Bootstrap v3.0.3 ), JQuery ( jquery-1.10.2.js ). My folder

```
bootstrap/
|---index.html
├── css/
│   ├── bootstrap.css
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   ├── bootstrap-theme.css
│   └── bootstrap-theme.min.css
├── js/
│   ├── bootstrap.js
│   ├── jquery-1.10.2.js
│   └── bootstrap.min.js
└── fonts/
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

This is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <input type='text' name='text'>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: *What* isn't working?

Comment: If you expect the input to look like a Bootstrap input change it to.. `<input type='text' name='text' class='form-control'>`

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap, when I click to text input it is not showing blue light around the input

Comment: Thanks Skelly, it is working after adding class='form-control'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap doesn't apply the class on controls by default. You need to assign the class to `input` control to see the effect.

Use `class="form-control"` with input controls like this

```
<input type='text' name='text' class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the two script tags for jquery and boostrap into the head section. Or if you don't want it in the head, try putting it before your content.